# Sencha Touch Google map memory leak?

Tags: ios, google-maps, sencha-touch

We are developing a Sencha Touch based app that utilizes a Google map in one of the views; however, we are stuck on what appears to be a memory leak (~15M) that is apparently caused by pushing the view containing the map onto the navigation stack.  I don't understand why, but when the view is popped, it seems as if the map resources are either not being freed, or are not being freed in a timely fashion (it is very easy to crash the app by repeatedly pushing the map view).  I was able to reproduce this issue using a very minimal phonegap + sencha + ios setup.   All i did was the following:

1. create a subview containing the google map:

   ```
   Ext.define('Memleak.view.Subview', {
       extend: 'Ext.Panel',
       xtype: 'subview',
       requires: [
           'Ext.TitleBar',
           'Ext.Map',
       ],
       config:
           {
               title: 'Map',
               iconCls: 'action',
               items: [
                   {
                       xtype: 'map',
                       id: 'theMap'
                   }
               ]
           }
   });
   ```
2. add a button to the main view that pushes the subview onto the navigation view stack.  i did this in Ext.application#launch to keep it minimal:

   ```
   launch: function() {
       // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
       Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

       var view = Ext.create('Ext.NavigationView', {
           fullscreen: true,
           items: [{
               items: [{
                   xtype: 'button',
                   text: 'MAP',
                   handler: function () {
                       view.push({
                           xtype: 'subview'
                       });

                   }
               }]
           }]
       });
   },
   ```
3. add map style to app.css:

   ```
   #theMap {
       height: 500px;
       width: 500px;
   }
   ```

To observe the memory leak, deploy the sencha project to ios and run it in the simulator and click on the debug tab to observe the memory usage, then just keep tapping the MAP and Back buttons.  It takes about 15 seconds to crash the app on my iPhone 4S.

I am really hoping this is something stupid / silly that we are doing wrong, that can be easily corrected.  Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The memory leak is in google maps, and is caused by simply creating and destroying a google map.  Google is aware of the issue and has not yet fixed it.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3803#makechanges